# Syntax Error - Unexpected Token - Region / State, OpenCart

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, opencart

http://www.yourvinyls.co.uk
I‘m looking for a fix for my billing details as no one can get further then region / state as the field options are blank.

Please could you help me?

I Also keep receiving this error, I’m unsure if its related to the same issue

> 2014-04-24 20:26:53 – PHP Notice: Undefined index: recurring in catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/template/module/cart.tpl on line 21

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. This website is to only trade inside United Kingdom too.

Comment: http://www.yourvinyls.co.uk/catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/template/module/cart.tpl is forbidden for us to access (probably a good thing, but we can't help much).

Comment: At least you're using error reporting. Now it's time to find the culprit. Got some code to show us? Or, at least show us some code including a few lines above line 21. Many a time, the error isn't always on that given line, but above it (somewhere). We can't guess.

Comment: Looking at the code its actually got nothing to do with my current problem sorry! It's to do with the state and region input when you are checking out with an item in the basket. Try buying an item using a guest account and then you'll have an error pop up saying the below, also the field is actually blank so you can't even select anything

Comment: Any ideas? - Really appreicate some help on this as I'm a little stumped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, You have use OpenCart 1.5.6.1. but, I think, Your OpenCart & custom theme is not same correct version. Follow below steps.

## Step 1

Go to: catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/ & then Copy below 3 files.

shipping_address.tpl
payment_address.tpl
guest_shipping.tpl

## Step 2

Go to: catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/template/checkout/ & then Replace it 3 files. & then check it.

Comment: Thanks your you're input, I tried doing that am I'm still having the same error

Comment: My opencart is Version 1.5.6.1 and Shoppica is 2.2.4 if that helps

Comment: Here, You will need to contact from shoppica2 theme support.

Comment: I have! 3 days ago and they're not replying - so frustrating. Thank you for trying to help